# Copy every 1000th row to a new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

- I have a workbook with 167 sheets
- Each Sheet has 1000 rows.
- I need a new sheet that has a list of all the last rows from each sheet.

So I will end up with a sheet containing 167 rows that has the 1000th row from each sheet copied over to the new sheet.

Comment: What part of your code and/or formula isn't working?  If you show us what you have tried, maybe we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent, free addin, [ASAP Utilities](http://www.asap-utilities.com/download-asap-utilities.php) that offers this functionality amongst many other options.

The utiltity you need is [Sheets » Put together rows or columns from several sheets..](http://www.asap-utilities.com/asap-utilities-excel-tools-tip.php?tip=36&utilities=20&lang=en_us)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'INDIRECT'.  You would need to put your sheet names into the first column, and the column identifiers ('A', 'B', 'C' etc) in the first row like

[image]

Then you can use the following starting from B2, and copying down and across:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!"&B$1&"1000")
```

This tells Excel that the text result of the formula is actually a reference to a specific cell, using the contents of the cells in the formula ($A2 and B$1) as part of that text string.

Comment: Manually typing in sheet names and column identifiers of 167 sheets is just downright ridiculous. A VBA Solution is far more practical.

Comment: Agreed, I certainly wouldn't use this approach unless you can flash fill the sheet names etc...usually if the data belongs on a summary sheet there's a pattern to the sheet names that suits flash filling - eg: Jan, Feb, Mar... or Week 1, Week 2 Week 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for VBA, I have commented the code so you can see what each line does.

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim lastShtName As String

' ** COUNTER FOR EACH ROW, INCREMENT EACH TIME A ROW IS COPIED
rowCounter = 1

' ************************************************
' **** SET SHEET NAME VARIABLE FOR LAST SHEET ****

           lastShtName = "LastSheet"

' ************************************************
' ************************************************

' ** LOOP THROUGH SHEETS
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    ' ** LOOP THROUGH ALL SHEETS EXCEPT FOR LAST SHEET, WHICH DATA IS PASTED ON. UPDATE SHEET NAME TO MATCH
    If sht.Name <> lastShtName Then

        ' ** COPY WHOLE ROW
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(lastShtName).Range("A" & rowCounter).EntireRow.Value = sht.Range("A" & 1000).EntireRow.Value

        ' ** INCREMENT COUNTER
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

    End If

' ** CONTINUE LOOP
Next sht

End Sub
```